# Get Count/Length/Size of Kendo UI DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am tring to get count of Kendo UI DropDownList but I am not getting right value. By taking count of Kendo UI, I want to remove last item from Kendo DropDownList.
I tried following but not working:

1.

```
var dropDown = $("#RoleDrp").data("kendoDropDownList");
var len = dropDown.value().length+1;
var itemToRemove = dropDown.dataSource.at(len);
dropDown.dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
dropDown.select(0);
```

I am getting length as 6 but I have total 13 items in DropDownList.

2.

```
var len = dropDown.length;
```

I am getting undefined.

Comment: try this :-var dropDown = $("#RoleDrp").data("kendoDropDownList");

var lengthOfDropDown=dropDown.dataSource._data.length;

Comment: you shouldn't access _ variables directly in kendo controls unless you're in the console debugger.  Use the getter.  You don't know if you have access to it or not as it could be scoped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hey try this code to get length of kendo dropdown list:-

```
var dropDown = $("#RoleDrp").data("kendoDropDownList");
var len =dropDown.dataSource.data().length;
alert(len);
```

Thanks

Comment: GR8. It is working. Thanks... I searched all over google but didnt get soln. For removing item I just have to do len-1.